# What is the difference between LVL 1.9 and 2.0?

Tags: wood, framing, structural, lumber

A structural engineer gave me a header design using beams made from LVL 1.9.  Looking around, I'm seeing more LVL 2.0 available locally.  What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LVL is laminated veneer lumber.  The numbers 1.9 and 2.0 refer to the Modulus of Elasticity which is a measure of the stiffness of the beam.  I would seriously doubt that there is any meaningful difference between 1.9 and 2.0 rated beams.

Answer (score 1):

You could believe 1.9e and 2.0e is meaningless right up to the point that your building inspector shuts down your job.
Best practice-- ask your inspector.